# How to restrict YouTube access to members of a certain domain

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to restrict access to a YouTube video to members of a certain domain?

For example, only those who log in to YouTube with an `@example.com` address can view the video.

Answer (score 1):

[Domain restrictions are only available for channels using the Content Owner (CMS).](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625) And unless the company you're working with is *really* important, getting into the CO is near-impossible.